# HTML5 multi video screen

Tags: html, html5-video

I have multiple video tags in single screen with absolute position and want to get that longer video from multiple and when longer video ends want to execute code.

```
<div style="width:1320px;height:1080px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div style="width:600px;height:1080px;position:absolute;left:1321px;top:0px;z-index:0;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
<div style="width:1000px;height:600px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:200px;z-index:5;">
    <video preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source src="3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="3.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

How can i do it?

Thanks,
Bhumi

Comment: please provide us some code to see what you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand it well, you have multiple videos on one page, and when the longest one ends playing, you want to execute code?

Then you'd do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var longestVid = "";
   $("video").each(function() {
       if (longestVid == "" || longestVid.duration < this.duration)
          longestVid = this;
   });

  //To loop all others:
  $("video").not($(longestVid)).attr("loop","loop");

   $(longestVid).on("ended",function() {

      //This code will execute when the longest video on the page ends playing.

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i repeat other videos till longer video ends? otherwise blank screen comes

Comment: @BhumiShah `<video src="" loop/>"

Comment: yeah loop is fine but need to add else condition for loop means for other video only?

Comment: Getting error like SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Are you sure , will it work because video tag don't have id attribute?

Comment: @BhumiShah I changed that as well.

Comment: getting NaN for duration